# Using External .jars compile time vs run time

Tags: java, opengl, jar, jogl

I'm trying to break into java and game programming using opengl. I built jogl and gluegen using ant and all junit tests ran successfully. However, when I attempt to run a simple OpenGL test program it gives me a "Could not find or load main class..." error. When compiling the program I enter:

```
javac -cp etc...\jogl-all.jar;etc...\gluegen-rt.jar filename.java
```

into the command line and I receive no compile-time errors. Then I attempt to run the program using:

```
java -cp etc...\jogl-all.jar;etc...\gluegen-rt.jar filename
```

and it tells me it cannot locate the main class.

Is this an error caused by using the external .jars? Or am I not using the -cp function properly? Any help would be appreciated!

The following is the code I'm trying to run:

```
import com.jogamp.opengl.*;
import com.jogamp.newt.event.WindowAdapter;
import com.jogamp.newt.event.WindowEvent;
import com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow;
import com.jogamp.common.type.*;

public class SimpleScene {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        GLProfile glp = GLProfile.getDefault();
        GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(glp);

        GLWindow window = GLWindow.create(caps);
        window.setSize(300, 300);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setTitle("NEWT Window Test");

        window.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowDestroyNotify(WindowEvent arg0) {
                System.exit(0);
            };
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `filename.java` contain a correctly declared main method?  Show the code for `filename.java`.

Comment: And ist filename.class part of the class path? It's not found otherwise. The current directory is not part of the class path by default.

Comment: I attempted to include the directory that the source code and .class  file are found within in the -cp header. That didn't work, do I need to include the actual .class file in the classpath?

Comment: @PeterHope : Please share relevant sections code filename.java and ant file(edit to question)

Comment: "Trying to break into java and game programming using opengl" and you start right away compiling jogl and gluegen? :)
Anyway, did you try to run your code in a standard way using an editor and attaching already-compiled libs?

Comment: You can just add jogamp-fat.jar into your classpath or merge it with your own JAR, it will be a lot easier. Otherwise, look at this: http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/JogAmp_JAR_File_Handling